# How to make a LinearLayout use the rest of the room that's left

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have this XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/surface"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="344dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/down"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/down"
        android:src="@drawable/right" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/down"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/down"
        android:src="@drawable/left" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/up"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right"
        android:src="@drawable/up" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/down"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/up"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/down" />
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And I would like to make the `LinearLayout` "surface" take all the of the room that's left (in height). Right now its height is 344dp because I don't know how to do so, and the size changes regards to the device. How can I accomplish having the `LinearLayout`'s surface take up all of the remaining height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change to this:

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/surface"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: when i do that it covers the RelativeLayout

Comment: Maybe change android:layout_height="fill_parent" for android:layout_height="match_parent"